# Abrir arquivo texto em pacote Python

Tags: python, arquivo

Estou criando um pacote Python onde um dos meus programas precisa abrir um arquivo texto para ler algumas informações. Esse arquivo fica no mesmo diretório do meu fonte. Quando rodo o programa no interpretador eu simplesmente faço

```
with open("AtomProva.atp") as f:
    input = f.readlines()
```

e ele abre o arquivo normalmente.
No entanto, quando crio um pacote que roda esse programa ele dá o seguinte erro

> FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'AtomProva.atp'

Como faço para achar esse arquivo rodando minha função de dentro do pacote que estou criando?

Comment: Não sei como é a criação de pacotes mas com certeza você está com um problema de path. No seu código você passar um path relativo de um arquivo na mesma pasta do seu .py, na hora que vai rodar o pacote ele procura em outro lugar (não sei exatamente qual). Passe mais detalhes do que é e como usa esse pacote que dá pra chegar na solução.

Comment: É um pacote simples (uma pasta com um __init__.py, seu script mais o seu .atp) ou um pacote gerado com setuptools?

Answer (score 3):

Faz assim:

1- Obtenha o diretório de instalação do módulo:

```
import os
modulePath = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))
```

2- Use esse path para encontrar o arquivo:

```
fileName = '{}/AtomProva.atp'.format(modulePath)
with open(fileName) as f:
    input = f.readlines()
```

Se o seu arquivo estiver no pacote em algum outro local que não o módulo onde você está fazendo a leitura, use um caminho relativo, como por exemplo:

```
fileName = '{}/../../outro-local/AtomProva.atp'.format(modulePath)
```